# Are non-commercial vessels leaving the US required to make a passenger manifest available to the US government?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

The background for this question is the lack of any formal exit (emigration) procedures when exiting the US. Instead, when such exit records are required, the government relies on airlines' passenger manifests and foreign countries' entry records. Airlines are mandated to maintain the manifests and provide them to the government when needed. Are non-commercial operators of air and sea vessels similarly required to?

Comment: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/4.94 is relevant for vessels.

Comment: @JonCuster that same part of the CFR is where the commercial passenger manifest requirement is regulated (at [19 CFR 4.64](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/4.64)). The absence of such a requirement for noncommercial vessels in that part may be as close as we're going to get to an authoritative statement that it is not required.  Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @phoog - I guess I'd say I'd feel happier if somebody with actual experience departing US waters would chime in. There have to be some folks from Florida on this SE who go to the Bahamas...

Comment: @JonCuster fair enough.  I have a friend I can ask, but I won't see him until Monday at the earliest.